# Tweet message and image in twitter

Tags: twitter, titanium

I am using `titanium_oauth`, `oauth.js`, and `sha1.js` file from Github.

```
var oauth = new TitaniumOAuth('xxxxxdd','mmmddd');
```

Login of Twitter app is open, but how to share text and image by `oauth`?

Please help I am new in titanium.

Answer (score 0):

Use social_plus for both image and text sharing

http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/blog/post/33810421717/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-posting-images-to-twitter-with-social_plus-js

it works with latest twitter api

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you use one of the latest Titanium SDKs from http://builds.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html . I got errors when using 3.2.3GA and 3.3.0GA